# How to reorder patches of git guilt patch series?

Tags: git, mercurial

The `guilt` tool ease the patch management over a git repository. It is barely equivalent to the Mq extension of Mercurial SCM.

I have a series of several patches on my repo. I want to re-order the series of patches.

In the Mq extension, there is a `--move` argument to the `qpush` command to do such re-ordering.
The `guilt push` command does not allow such argument.

How to perform such re-ordering operation on a guilt patch series?

Answer (score 1):

For now the only solution I found is to manually modify the guilt `series` file.

This file is located under: `<repo_bdir>/.git/patches/<branch_name>/series`

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit the series file:

```
guilt series -e
```

I recommend doing this without any patches applied, or at least without any patches applied whose order you're modifying.